# Stability of homogeneous linear systems (Eigenvalues)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> > Consider $A(t)\equiv A\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. Show: $y=0$ is stable for $\dot{y}=Ay$ if and only if 
> >     $$
> > \begin{cases}\Re(\lambda_j)\leqslant 0\text{ for all Eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ of $A$}\\\text{if $\Re(\lambda_j)=0$ then $\lambda_j$ is semi-simple. } \end{cases}
> > $$

Could you please help me to prove that? I am a bit overstrained with that to be honest.

Maybe somebody can help!

With lots of greetings

math12

**Update 3**: My proof

> > Later, I will use the theorem, that the trivial solution $y=0$ of a system $\dot{y}=Ay$ is stable if and only if for a fundamentalmatrix $Y$ of the system it is 
> >     $$
> > \sup_{t\geq 0}\lvert Y(t)\rvert <\infty.
> > $$

Now to the proof itself:

The system $\dot{x}=Ax$ has the Fundamentalmatrix $e^{At}$.

$e^{At}$ can be written as a matrix $Y$, which columns are the $\mathbb{R}^n$- valued functions
$$
e^{\lambda t}p_0(t), e^{\lambda t}p_1(t),\ldots,e^{\lambda t}p_{k-1},\\e^{pt}\cos\sigma t q_0(t),e^{pt}\cos\sigma t q_1(t),\ldots,e^{pt}\cos\sigma t p_{m-1}(t),\\e^{pt}\sin\sigma t r_0(t),e^{pt}\sin\sigma t r_1(t),\ldots,e^{pt}\sin\sigma t r_{m-1}(t),
$$

whereat $\lambda$ runs through all real Eigenvalues of $A$ and $p\pm i\sigma$ runs through all complex Eigenvalues of $A$. And the coordinates of the functions $p_i(t), i=0,\ldots,k-1$ and $q_j(t),r_j(t), j=0,\ldots,m-1$ are polynoms in $t$.

($k$ is the algebraic multiplicity of the respective real Eigenvalue and $m$ is the algebraic multiplicity of the respective conjugated complex pair of Eigenvalues  $p\pm i\sigma$.)

Moreover, it is $\lim_{t\to\infty} t^n e^{\mu t}=0$, if $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $\mu<0$

and

$\lim_{t\to\infty} t^n e^{\mu t}=\infty$, if $n\in\mathbb{N}_0$ and $\mu\geq 0$

---

Now, let the trivial solution $y=0$ be stable. Then it is $\sup_{t\geq 0}\lvert Y(t)\rvert<\infty$, or to put in in other words, there is a $M>0$ such that $\lvert Y(t)\rvert < M<$ for all $t\geq 0$.

Now take the matrix norm that is defined by the vector norm. Then this means that the norm of each columns of $Y$ has to be bounded. Because in each columns of $Y$ there are functions as mentioned above, the real parts of the Eigenvalues have to be negative (otherwise the norm of each column would not be bounded) or the real parts can be zero but then the polynoms have to be constants (otherwise the norms of the columns would not be bounded), which means that the Eigenvalues are then semi-simple.

Now the other way round. Let all real parts of the Eigenvalues of $A$ be non-positive and in the case they are zero, the Eigenvalues are semi-simple.
Then this means that the norm of each column of $Y$ is bounded and this means that the norm of $Y$ itself is bounded, i.e. $y=0$ is stable.

Could you please tell me if my proof is allright or improvable?

Comment: Now all you need to do is to look at the elements of those matrices and study their behaviour when $t\to\infty$. For example, $G(t)$ is bounded peridic; if $a=0$, then non-diagonal blocks in $e^{K_\mu t}$ become unbounded, hence the zero solution is not stable; thus, we can't have non-diagonal blocks, which leads to all eigenvalues with zero real part being semisimple. An analogous reasoning will help you to conclude on all remainig cases.

Comment: As a side remark, the result on stability holds even for complex matrices: zero solution is stable iff there're no eigenvalues in right half-plane and all eigenvalues on imaginary axis have equal geometric and algebraic multiplicities.

Comment: please see "Update 2"

Comment: Now in "Update 3" I added my final proof. Could you please have a look on it? Thank you!

Comment: The space of matrices is finite-dimensioned, so all norms are equivalent. Chose the norm $\|B\|=\max_{i,j}|b_{ij}|$, then study elements of $Y(t)$ in the basis of eigenvectors and generalised eigenvectors (i.e. such basis that the matrix of the system is a Jordan normal matrix). Then the elements of $Y(t)$ are described as you wrote in your update **2**. Thanks to the choice of matrix norm, you need to find conditions such that all elements are bounded for $t\in(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Update 3 looks correct, up to some typos=)

Comment: Typos? For example?

Comment: You note polynomials as $p$, then use the same letter to denote real part of other eigenvalues. In the second list of functions (with $\cos$) you start with $q$ for polynomials, but end with $p$ (artefact of copypasting, I think). But the logic in the reasoning is correct.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! I'll correct these typos and then I am happy I made it. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Steps to undertake:

1) Prove that the solution has the form $y(t)=e^{tA}y(0)$

2) Find what $e^{tA}$ looks like and why we need Jordan normal form of $A$. Look how $e^{tJ}$ looks like when $J$ is a Jordan normal matrix.

3) Study the behaviour of the elements of $e^{tJ}$ when $t\to\infty$ with respect to eigenvalues of $J$

4) Conclude.

If you have any questions regarding the above steps, ask in comments.

Comment: If you do not mind, I ask my questions in my original post, because I think I'll need more signs and place.

Comment: added my thoughts to (1) and (2)